# Entity Framework database partition

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I have extensive data and want to partition it into multiple databases based on date range.

How do I load the multiple `DbContext`s and combine them into one using Entity Framework? Is this possible?

TIA!

Comment: I may be wrong, but you configure a partition in your database itself, code doesn't change in your application.

Answer (score 0):

For example if u have three db's db1,2,3 have multiple connection strings and create a linked server of db2 and db3 to db1 so that db1 is your main db and create dbcontext for each db and make your db1 as your combined dbcontext of 2 and 3 .
Use repository pattern to inject these multiple databases.